# FabricJS Bullets Removed from PDF

Tags: canvas, fabricjs, tcpdf

I have a graphics editor built using canvas and FabricJS. I am outputting a SVG to the server, then creating a PDF with the SVG file using the TCPDF library. However, most of the bullet points are stripped from the PDF, although they appear in the SVG (see screenshots below). I have been searching for hours for a solution, but all I can come up with is that it is removing the bullet because it is not a UTF8 character and is not included in the custom font families we are using. The bullets only seem to work for the standard font families.

I have seen several methods of creating bullets using TCPDF, however none of them have addressed bullets that are inside of an SVG file. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Canvas Screenshot (All Fonts Have Bullets)**
[image]

**PDF Output (Most Bullets Stripped)**
[image]

---

Also, here is the PHP code that generates the PDF:

```
require(PATH TO TCPDF."/tcpdf.php");

$width = $brochure_data["total_width_inches"];  
$height = $brochure_data["total_height_inches"]; 
$orientation = ($height>$width) ? 'P' : 'L';  

$page_size = array($width, $height);

$pdf = new TCPDF($orientation, "in", $page_size, true, 'UTF-8', false);

//Import custom fonts
$fonts=get_fonts();
foreach($fonts AS $font){ 
    if($font["font_source"]){
        TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont(PATH TO FONTS."/".$font["font_source"], 'TrueType', '', 32);
    }
}

// remove default header/footer
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(0, 0, 0, true);

// set auto page breaks false
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);

//Loop through each SVG and create a new page for each
foreach($svg_images AS $svg_image){

    // add a page
    $pdf->AddPage($orientation, $page_size);

    $pdf->ImageSVG($svg_image, $x=0, $y=0, $w=$brochure_data["total_width_inches"]*300, $h=$brochure_data["total_height_inches"]*300, $link='', $align='', $palign='', $border=0, $fitonpage=true);

}

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf_filename=BROCHURE FILENAME.".pdf";
$pdf->Output($pdf_filename, 'F');
```

---

Here is a snippet from the SVG file. The bullet would work if the font family was Arial or a standard font, but not with the specified font.

```
<g transform="translate(714 287.2896)"> <text font-family="Lobster" font-size="24" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(51,51,51); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" > <tspan x="-63.61" y="-8.17" fill="#333333">• Demo Text</tspan> <tspan x="0" y="23.29" fill="#333333"></tspan> </text> </g>
```

Comment: In [this discussion](https://sourceforge.net/p/tcpdf/discussion/435311/thread/2ddc735e/) the developer stated that some "advanced text" features are not supported. However, this may have changed since 2012. Could you please post a small example of source code from an SVG that triggers the issue?

Comment: I added a snippet to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More research is needed to determine the exact source of the problem, however, I think this answer should help you.

The problem, as you stated, is related to how TCPDF is handling characters that are not in the font. The `• (U+2022)` is not a character in the Lobster font, so when viewing the SVG in your browser a fallback font is used. However, this is not occurring when the PDF is being shown in your PDF viewer.

### Possible Solution

I don't know the reason this worked when I tested it, but if you allow TCPDF to autodetect the font type it will add it as a `TrueTypeUnicode` font. This resulted in a fallback font being used for missing characters. The downside of this is that you are relying on the fonts that ship with each PDF viewer. These fonts can be inconsistent, so you can't guarantee what the PDF will look like. Testing the file in multiple PDF viewers and on multiple computers would be a good idea.

**Note:** TCPDF doesn't appear to overwrite the font files it creates, so you will likely need to delete the following files for each font so it will recreate them: `lobster.ctg.z, lobster.php, lobster.z`

### Other Possible Solutions

- You could add the missing characters to the fonts you are embedding so that you can guarantee the appearance of each character. This is a solution that I have used in the past, but it can be time-consuming.
- You may be able to convert the text to paths, so embedding the fonts in the PDF would not be required. This is just an idea that I have not tested and it has its own downsides.

### Example

Example SVG

```xml
<svg width="500" height="500">
    <text
      font-family="Lobster"
      font-size="24">
      <tspan x="50" y="100">• Demo Text</tspan></text>
</svg>
```

Example PHP

```php
<?php
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');
$pdf = new TCPDF();
// Leave $fonttype blank, so TCPDF will autodetect it.
// May need to delete font files already generated.
TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('../fonts/Lobster.ttf');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->ImageSVG("images/example.svg", $x=0, $y=0, $w=200, $h=200);
$pdf->Output("example.pdf", 'I');
```

Comment: I tried your first solution and it did correct the bullet issue, however now there appears to be a new issue. The letter spacing is way off for several of the fonts that we are using, and some of the fonts don't render properly at all. However it is only a handful of fonts that have this issue, so we will probably just remove those fonts for the time being. Thanks so much for your assistance!